# Iterating through lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
A = [(1,1,1,2,2), (1,1,3,2,2), (1,1,6,2,2), (1,1,5,2,2), (1,1,2,5,2), (2,1,1,1,2) ...]
```

I'm running the elements through a simple for-loop like so:

```
n = len(A);
for p in [0..n-1] :
     a1 = A[p][5*p]
     a2 = A[(p+1)][5*(p+1)]
     .
     .
```

and I'm getting: 'int' object is not iterable. I've no idea why this isn't working.

quick edit:

Ideal output: every a1 is like--a1 = A[0][0], then a1 = A[1][5], then a1 = A[2][10] and on.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Trying to print certain elements of the tuple. to get an ouput like this: a1 = A[0][0] and then next a1=[1][5], and then a1=[2][10]

Comment: could you write, what are A[0][0], A[1][5] and A[2][10] in your example?

Comment: My indices were very much off. I figured it out. Problem solved. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you are trying to do:

```
for p in A:
    print p[0],p[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're used to matlab. Try:

```
for p in range(n):
```

Anyway, you'll get index problems with using `A[p][5*p].

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm still getting not iterable. I've used the method I showed above many times before and gotten it work with generating lists.

Comment: `[0..n-1]` does actually work. But my index was incorrect as you said. I've figured out why I getting this error!

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? For CPython 2.7, this gives a syntax error. Also Google didn't show me any hint that this is Python syntax.